# How to use Console Kernel in Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, kernel, laravel-5.4

I am reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/lifecycle#lifecycle-overview) at Laravel under the heading `Architecture Concepts`.

I am unable to understand application and usage of Console Kernel .(not the Http Kernel)
However, I googled out and found these links

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.html
https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Contracts/Console/Kernel.html

But I can't understand anything with that API !

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The HTTP Kernel is used to process requests that come in through the web (HTTP). Website requests, AJAX, that kind of stuff.

The Console Kernel is used when you interact with your application from the command line. If you use `artisan`, or when a scheduled job is processed, or when a queued job is processed, all of these actions go through the Console Kernel.

Basically, if you go through `index.php`, you'll be using the HTTP Kernel. Most everything else will be using the Console Kernel.